# how to disable search bar in google places api and give your own static search term

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

So I want to develop an android app that uses the new google places api to display the nearby hospitals to the users location I a want the search bar in the place picker widget to be disabled. But I am neither able to specify my search term nor am I able to set disable the search bar or make it invisible. Is this even possible? Am I trying something completely different from what I should be using?
Here is the button on click that launches the widget

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                        new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();         
       Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                    | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have a feeling I am not going in the correct direction please guide me.

Comment: Can you show us what you want to implement? In android, if you're using the web to show the map, the initial implementation dont have the search box. To add search for places use [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Comment: my ambition was an app in which the user clicks the fragment tab and in front of him opens a list of nearby hospitals, this app would come in handy if there was any medical emergency emergency. i would be truly thankfull if you could link me any tutorial

Comment: Here's a forum how to hide search box:https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/NOLldtaEO-c